# How to delete "u'" before the attributes

Tags: python

When I load the JSON file and when I print it I get before each attribute a "u'"

how can I escape it ?

```
    try:
        with codecs.open('graphe.json', 'r', 'utf-8') as json_data:
            c = json.load(json_data)
            print c
    except IOError, e:
        print 'IOError : No file in input'
```

> {u'ressourcepath': u'D:\Stage_ete_2016\DjangoProject\resources\',
>   u'Nodes': [{u'title': [u'npq1', u'npq3', u'npq2'],....

the JSON

> {"ressourcepath": "D:\Stage_ete_2016\DjangoProject\resources\",
>   "Nodes": [{"title": ["npq1", "npq3", "npq2"],...

so the problem is that I use this dictionary to write a JavaScript code (template) and I must respect the JavaScript syntax (Vis js):
[image: the problem screenshot]

Comment: Why do you think you need to "delete" this character? What *practical* issue are you facing?

Comment: You except most likely having the wrong indent and u'' is the Python way to tell you, you got an Unicode string

Comment: You're not trying to print json. You're printing python `dict`

Comment: There is no `u` character in the string. You look at the **representation** of the string where the leading `u` shows that the string contains unicode data. If you print the string itself you will see no `u`.

Comment: I use this dict to build  a JavaScript code (django template ) to pint a network (vis js) but so I must delete th "u'" so that it will be no error syntax. **here is the probleme : **

Answer (score 2):

The `u` prefix means that those strings are unicode rather than 8-bit strings. The best way to not show the `u` prefix is to switch to Python 3, where strings are unicode by default. If that's not an option, the `str` constructor will convert from unicode to 8-bit, so simply loop recursively over the result and convert `unicode` to `str`. However, it is probably best just to leave the strings as unicode.

Comment: I must parse all the dict and then apply the str constructor to each key/value that is the only solution ?

Comment: exactly, you are right!